# Unable to use Mathematica Link in NetLogo 6.0

Tags: macos, wolfram-mathematica, netlogo

I was trying to connect Netlogo 6.0 and Mathematica 11 on my Mac OSX system (v10.11.6).
I have followed the installation instructions of the Netlogo Mathematica-Link: import NetLogo.m into Mathematica and load the package,
<< NetLogo`.

The problem is when I try to start NetLogo from Mathematica:
NLStart["/Applications/NetLogo 6.0/"] an error message appears

"Mathematica could not find your NetLogo installation directory /Applications/NetLogo 6.0/, Would you like to locate it?",

I find the NetLogo installation in /Applications/NetLogo 6.0/ but it does not work: "NLStart::netlogonotfound: NetLogo could not be found in: /Applications/NetLogo 6.0/".

I cannot guess what is going wrong, and I would ask you for help

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there was an oversight when packaging NetLogo 6. Thanks for reporting this problem! I've just created a release of Mathematica Link that can be dropped in with NetLogo 6.0 to make it functional. It's available for download  [here](https://github.com/NetLogo/Mathematica-Link/releases/tag/6.0.0-Patch). We'll include the fix in the next release of NetLogo.