# Recommended hotpatch for Mathematica Link to NetLogo 6 didn't work

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, netlogo

I have the same problem as the user who posted in "Unable to use Mathematica Link in NetLogo 6.0" ([Unable to use Mathematica Link in NetLogo 6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41537588/unable-to-use-mathematica-link-in-netlogo-6-0)). For me, the Mathematica Link seems to work fine with Netlogo version 5.3.1. Even after I attempted the recommended hotpatch (which was the answer to the original posted question on this topic), still no luck (I get the same error message posted in the original comment cited above). I tried extracting the hotpatch in the NetLogo 6.0 directory and in the NetLogo 6.0 / app subdirectory... neither seemed to work. I'm using a PC with Windows 7.

Any advice on how to properly install the patch would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you include a link to the previous question?

Comment: Also, instead of saying "no luck" and "didn't work", can you say exactly what happened instead? For example, was there an error message?

Comment: Sorry about that... I edited my original post to include the information that was missing.  Thanks for your reply!

Comment: Is the problem fixed in NetLogo 6.0.1?

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Comment: Can you include the full and exact text of the error message you are currently getting?

Comment: When I try to use NLStart[ ] and browse to the NetLogo folder in my C: drive, I get the following:  NLStart::netlogonotfound: NetLogo could not be found in: C:\Program Files\NetLogo 6.0.1\

Answer (score 0):

This fix is packaged with 6.0.1 and instructions on using it can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43289271/unable-to-use-link-between-netlogo-6-0-1-and-mathematica-11-1-on-a-64-bit-proces/43478234#43478234). If it's easy for you to upgrade to 6.0.1 I would recommend doing that over trying to install the 6.0 fix. I have verified that the fix works for 6.0, although the installation instructions don't seem to be correct.

My configuration:

- Windows 10 (don't have Windows 7 available, unfortunately)
- NetLogo 6.0 64-bit
- Windows 10 64-bit

The steps I took to install:

- Before starting, go to your NetLogo installation directory and rename the "Mathematica Link" directory to "Mathematica Link - original" (or delete it, if you prefer).
- When I downloaded the file, it extracted to somewhere in my Downloads folder. You may have to extract yourself, depending on your browser and OS configuration
- I copied the enclosed "Mathematica Link" folder (the one with the space in the name, not the "MathematicaLink" folder at the top level) to the NetLogo directory (not the "app" directory as mentioned in the instructions).

I then opened Mathematica and ran the following commands:

- File > Install > type: Package, source: From File, file: C:\Program Files\NetLogo 6.0.1\Mathematica Link\NetLogo.m, install name: NetLogo, install for this user only. Note that when selecting this file, Mathematica will use the last directory you opened, so when the file dialog opens, first navigate to the the top of the drive then navigate down to NetLogo 6.0.1 (using a NetLogo.m file from an older NetLogo version will almost certainly break Mathematica link, and this is a very easy mistake to make).
- Entered in the notebook (cannot code block this): <

  Entered in the notebook: `NLStart["C:\\Program File\\NetLogo 6.0.1"]` (note the double backslashes and no trailing backslash).

  The NetLogo window will open after a noticeable  delay (depending on your system speed and memory)

Edit:

I wanted to consolidate troubleshooting steps for future readers. I've introduced a new version of NetLogo.m available [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/NetLogo/Mathematica-Link/master/NetLogo.m), which users should download for troubleshooting purposes (it will be distributed with future versions of NetLogo). Some steps to using this:

1. Mathematica will cache old "NetLogo.m" files. You can find where these caches are by using the following commands in Mathematica:

   - `FileNameJoin[{ $BaseDirectory, "Applications" }]`
   - `FileNameJoin[{ $UserBaseDirectory, "Applications" }]`
2. Visit the directories obtained in Step 1 and delete all "NetLogo.m" files from them.
3. [Download the new version of NetLogo.m](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/NetLogo/Mathematica-Link/master/NetLogo.m)
4. Install the downloaded version of NetLogo.m (and run <<NetLogo`)
5. Run `NLDiagnostics["C:\\Program Files\\NetLogo 6.0.1"]` to determine what paths are being searched. This function will produce a hash as an output. The key `missingJars` should be an empty list (`{}`).
6. If you want to check java version, you can run `NLJavaDiagnostics[]`. The `javaVersion` returned should start with "1.8.0", the `javaArchitecture` returned should be "64".

Comment: Thank you for your message.  I tried your suggestion on my Windows 7 system and still no luck.  I even uninstalled and reinstalled my version of NetLogo 6.0.1 before starting... I get the following message at the NLStart[] step: "Mathematica could not find your NetLogo installation directory in: C?\Program Files\NetLogo 6.0.1.  Would you like to locate it?"  Even selecting OK and renavigating to the location doesn't seem to help.

Comment: My answer didn't originally show double-backslashes (my mistake when formatting). If you saw `C?\Program Files\NetLogo 6.0.1` and the dialog, it couldn't find it in the appropriate directory. Could you copy verbatim your invocation of `NLStart`?

Comment: Sure... here it is:  In[5]:= NLStart["C:\\Program Files\\NetLogo 6.0.1"]

During evaluation of In[5]:= NLStart::netlogonotfound: NetLogo could not be found in: C:\Program Files\NetLogo 6.0.1\

Out[5]= $Failed

Comment: Again, it seems to work fine with NetLogo 5.3.1.  It's versions 6.0 and 6.0.1 that seem to have problems.  Any way to compare how NetLogo has configured the link between versions 5.3.1 and the 6's to see what's up?

Comment: One thing I didn't consider in my first response is checking which version of Java Mathematica Link is using. I've added commands to do so below, under "Commands to determine Mathematica Java version". For me, the result is 1.8.0_92. Can you run the commands and post yours?

Comment: I also get the result 1.8.0_92.  Yet, I still get the same error message I indicated before at the "NLStart[]" command.  Very frustrating.

Comment: The version of java looks suitable (to be thorough, you could also check the `sun.arch.data.model` property, which should be "64"). I've edited my answer above to give two more commands which will be helpful in identifying which jar files Mathematica can find and which are missing. NetLogo will fail to load (with the error you describe) if any jar files are missing.

Comment: Thanks Robert. Still won't work.  Please let me know if I'm doing something wrong (which I readily admit is possible).  Here's my Mathematica 11 session: In[33]:= << NetLogo`

In[34]:= Select[NLJarPaths["C:\\Program Files\\NetLogo 6.0.1"], 
 Not[FileExistsQ]]

Out[34]= NLJarPaths[]

In[35]:= Select[
 NLJarPaths["C:\\Program Files\\NetLogo 6.0.1"], FileExistsQ]

Out[35]= NLJarPaths["C:\\Program Files\\NetLogo 6.0.1"]

In[36]:= NLStart[]

During evaluation of In[36]:= NLStart::netlogonotfound: NetLogo could not be found in: C:\Program Files\NetLogo 6.0.1\

Out[36]= $Failed

Comment: Sorry, my prior comment was made when I seem to have had something strange in my kernel. I'm figuring out how to get my results to be reproducible, as I still don't fully understand Mathematica's package system. I'll post again when I have something reproducible. In the meantime, you *may* be able to get this to work for you by playing around with Global / Notebook local context.

Comment: I'm not sure how to fix that.  I've uninstalled NetLogo 6, and even just tried uninstalling and reinstalling 6.0.1 so I'm not sure how/why that's happening.

Comment: Can you download an updated NetLogo.m from here (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/NetLogo/Mathematica-Link/master/NetLogo.m), install it and run `NLDiagnostics["C:\\Program Files\\NetLogo 6.0.1"]`? I've added a method which should help figure out what's going on here.

Comment: Thanks... I copied the recommended file to Notepad, named it NetLogo.m and replaced the NetLog.m files in the Mathematica Link and app/Mathematica Link folders (I'm not really sure why there are two Mathematica Link folders in NetLogo 6.0.1).  In Mathematica, after entering <<NetLogo`, the NLDiagnostics command you suggested simply returned to me the same exact command without the quotes. Not sure I carried out what you suggested correctly...

Comment: You may need to clear your kernel before loading the (new) NetLogo.m file (restarting Mathematica should do the trick). I have verified I am able to run <<NetLogo\` and NLDiagnostics[path to NetLogo] just fine from the file I posted, so it's an issue of getting that file to load into Mathematica correctly.

Comment: I'm still getting the same result as my last comment.  What is supposed to result from the NLDiagnostics command?  Even when I use it to call NetLogo 5.3.1 (for which Mathematica Link seems to work), it simply outputs the command back to me without the quotes.  I very much appreciate your helping me with this by the way... Thanks again.

Comment: I just found something that might be helpful: when installing a package in Mathematica, it copies the package into one of two directories $BaseDirectory / Applications (for system-wide installs) or $UserBaseDirectory / Applications (for single-user installs). I found it had cached an old version of NetLogo.m. Deleting this and reinstalling made things work properly. I've updated my answer above to clarify this.

Comment: YES!  This finally worked!  I did as instructed, loading the NetLogo.m file inside NetLogo… then when running <<NetLogo` in Mathematica it failed with a “Cannot open NetLogo`” error message.  I then manually replaced the NetLogo.m file you suggested into the two directories identified in Mathematica (not just in NetLogo itself) and then the <<NetLogo` command worked properly.  The NLDiagnostics showed an empty-string associated with missingJars like you said, and NLStart finally got NetLogo 6.0.1 running from within Mathematica.  Thank you so much for sticking with my annoying issue.

Comment: Terrific! I'm glad we finally got it working. I learned a lot in figuring out this problem and I really appreciate you continuing to let me know what was happening. Now that we've resolved this, I'll document this in case other users run into similar problems!