# Unable to use link between Netlogo 6.0.1 and Mathematica 11.1 on a 64 bit processor pc running Windows 10

Tags: windows, 64-bit, wolfram-mathematica, netlogo

I am unable to run the mathematica-netlogo link on my PC with a 64 bit processor running window 10. The versions of Netlogo and Mathematica are 6.0.1 and 11.1 Student Edition respectively.

The error arises when the function "NLStart[]" is run with the path of the Netlogo directory provided as an input to this function. The error message is as follows:

NLStart::netlogonotfound: NetLogo could not be found in: C:\Program Files\NetLogo 6.0.1\

Prior to this step, I successfully loaded the NetLogo Mathematica link package.

Any helpful suggestions to overcome this issue will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43209522/recommended-hotpatch-for-mathematica-link-to-netlogo-6-didnt-work

Answer (score 1):

I've just verified I was able to use NetLogo Mathematica Link with the following configuration:

- Mathematica 11.1.0.0
- NetLogo 6.0.1 64-bit
- Windows 10 64-bit

My Mathematica installation was untouched, as was my NetLogo installation - I did not have the Mathematica Link 6.0 hotfix installed for NetLogo 6.0.1. Also, NetLogo 6.0.1 was installed in "C:\Program Files\NetLogo 6.0.1" (some users choose to install to a different directory, or their primary drive is not lettered with "C:").

I opened Mathematica and ran the following commands:

- File > Install > type: Package, source: From File, file: C:\Program Files\NetLogo 6.0.1\Mathematica Link\NetLogo.m, install name: NetLogo, install for this user only. Note that when selecting this file, Mathematica will use the last directory you opened, so when the file dialog opens, first navigate to the the top of the drive then navigate down to NetLogo 6.0.1 (using a NetLogo.m file from an older NetLogo version will almost certainly break Mathematica link, and this is a very easy mistake to make).
- Entered in the notebook (cannot code block this): <<NetLogo`
- Entered in the notebook: `NLStart["C:\\Program Files\\NetLogo 6.0.1"]` (note the double backslashes and no trailing backslash).
- The NetLogo window will open after a slight delay (depending on your system speed and memory)

If you've followed these steps and are still unable to open Mathematica Link, please comment and we can continue to troubleshoot.

Edit:

I wanted to consolidate troubleshooting steps for future readers. I've introduced a new version of NetLogo.m available [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/NetLogo/Mathematica-Link/master/NetLogo.m), which users should download for troubleshooting purposes (it will be distributed with future versions of NetLogo). Some steps to using this:

1. Mathematica will cache old "NetLogo.m" files. You can find where these caches are by using the following commands in Mathematica:

   - `FileNameJoin[{ $BaseDirectory, "Applications" }]`
   - `FileNameJoin[{ $UserBaseDirectory, "Applications" }]`
2. Visit the directories obtained in Step 1 and delete all "NetLogo.m" files from them.
3. [Download the new version of NetLogo.m](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/NetLogo/Mathematica-Link/master/NetLogo.m)
4. Install the downloaded version of NetLogo.m (and run <<NetLogo`)
5. Run `NLDiagnostics["C:\\Program Files\\NetLogo 6.0.1"]` to determine what paths are being searched. This function will produce a hash as an output. The key `missingJars` should be an empty list (`{}`).
6. If you want to check java version, you can run `NLJavaDiagnostics[]`. The `javaVersion` returned should start with "1.8.0", the `javaArchitecture` returned should be "64".

Comment: I followed your instructions. I'm still unable to open the Mathematica Link. The error occurs at the execution of the third step mentioned above. The error message is as follows.

NLStart::nopath: NetLogo cannot be started without a valid NetLogo 4.0 path

I confirm that the location of the NetLogo directory in my PC is 'C:\\Program Files\\NetLogo 6.0.1'.

Comment: Did you see a file selection dialog before you saw the error?

Also, can you paste the exact text you used with `NLStart` here. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I did. File selection dialog had the text "Mathematica could not find your NetLogo installation directory in: C:\Program Files\NetLogo 6.0.1. Would you like to locate it?" The exact text that I used for NLStart: NLStart["C:\\Program Files\\NetLogo 6.0.1"]. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Robert, I wonder whether you're waiting on any more information from me to continue to troubleshoot.

Comment: The information you've provided seems correct and using the same process for me starts NetLogo. I think maybe the difference is in which version of Java Mathematica is using. Can you enter the commands I posted above under "Determine mathematica java version" and let me know the result?

Comment: Cheers. I ran the four commands sequentially in mathematica. The final output from running the command 'System`getProperty["java.version"]' is 1.8.0_121.

Comment: The version of java looks suitable (to be thorough, you could also check the `sun.arch.data.model` property, which should be "64"). I've edited my answer above to give two more commands which will be helpful in identifying which jar files Mathematica can find and which are missing. NetLogo will fail to load (with the error you describe) if any jar files are missing.

Comment: I checked the sun.arch.data.model property, which returned to be 64. When I ran the command "Select[NLJarPaths["C:\\Program Files\\NetLogo 6.0.1"], Not[FileExistsQ]] ",  "NLJarPaths[]" was the output. When I ran the command Select[NLJarPaths["C:\\Program Files\\NetLogo 6.0.1"], "NLJarPaths["C:\\Program Files\\NetLogo 6.0.1"]" was the output.

Comment: Can you download an updated NetLogo.m here (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/NetLogo/Mathematica-Link/master/NetLogo.m), install it and run `NLDiagnostics["C:\\Program Files\\NetLogo 6.0.1"]`? I've added a method which should help figure out what's going on here.

Comment: Once I've followed your instructions, the output from running NLDiagnostics is as follows: <|"providedPath" -> "C:\\Program Files\\NetLogo 6.0.1", 
 "jarLookupPaths" -> {"C:\\Program Files\\NetLogo \
6.0.1\\app\\NetLogo.jar", 
   "C:\\Program Files\\NetLogo 6.0.1\\Mathematica \
Link\\mathematica-link.jar"}, 
 "foundJars" -> {"C:\\Program Files\\NetLogo 6.0.1\\Mathematica \
Link\\mathematica-link.jar"}, "missingJars" -> {}|>

Comment: I just found something that might be helpful: when installing a package in Mathematica, it copies the package into one of two directories $BaseDirectory / Applications (for system-wide installs) or $UserBaseDirectory / Applications (for single-user installs). I found it had cached an old version of NetLogo.m. Deleting this and reinstalling NetLogo made things work properly. I've updated my answer above to clarify this.

Comment: You're a godsend! Finally, it works. Thanks for your patience and persistence in troubleshooting through this issue.